# keyboardType 'number-pad' doesn't work on android emulator or android device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am quite new on react-native. I have tried to build simple app. TextInput component's prop keyboardType 'number-pad' doesn't work properly. I dont understand why. Help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the TextInput props, try using keyboardType ={'phone-pad'}

<TextInput keyboardType = {'phone-pad'}>